# how to show variable from JavaScript in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, variables

I have one file with name : `java.js` (JavaScript file) and I have one variable in it `(var link = "this is test";)` and I want display this value in html file but I don't know about it.

please guide me that how to show value variable from js in html.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp  0,22 seconds google research

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make a div with id in HTML `<div id="show-here"></div>` and put this to your script file

```
var link = "this is test";
var div = document.getElementById('show-here');
div.innerHTML = link;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `write` method of `document`.

`document.write(link);`

You can find some exemples [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp).

Comment: If you suggest `document.write` you should explain when it is save to use and what the pitfalls of `document.write` are. `w3cschools` is a really bad source for this (i is generally a bad source) because they explain nothing about the downsides of `document.write`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include that .JS file and you can the print the value of the variable like this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="PATH" />
```

You can print the contents using:-

```
document.write();
```